# Linear Algebra-Intersections and Distances in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Self-study here. I need to check my answers.

1. What is the relationship between the line $x=x_0+at,y=y_0+bt, z=z_0+ct$ and the plane $ax+by+cz=0$? Explain.
2. T or F. If $a, b$ and $c$ are not all zero, then the line $x=at$, $y=bt$, $z=ct$ is perpendicular to the plane $ax+by+cz=0$.
3. T or F. If $u, v$ and $w$ are vectors in $3$-space such that $u+v+w=0$, then the three vectors lie in some plane. (Yep, you read it right, some plane. Is the book making a typo?).
4. T or F. The equation $x=tv$ represents a line for every vector $v$ in $2$-space.

Comment: What are your answers?

Comment: 1. Perpendicularity of the line and the plane.
2. True. Normal of the plane will be parallel to the line.
3. True if you mean "some". Because all vectors lie in "some" plane. But if you meant "same" then no, false: vectors in 3D can cancel each other out.
4. No, not for (0,0).

Can you tell me if there is any other aspect of the questions I missed, any insight I may have missed?

Comment: I agree with your 1,2,4 answers. To me question 3 is T of F: If $u,v,w$ are vectors in 3-space such that $u+v+w=0$, then there exists a plane $P$ such that each of $u,v,w$ lies in $P$. And the answer is True! so you might want to think about that some more....

Comment: @GregMartin , thanks! I have some doubts about what you just said for 3. "To me question 3 is T of F:" What did you mean by T of F? Are you sure the book says that the three vectors lie in the same plane P? (I have to admit English is a 2nd language for me.)

Comment: Is there any way I can prove that "If u,v,w are vectors in 3-space such that u+v+w=0, then there exists a plane P such that each of u,v,w lies in P." is true? I can't seem to think of any way.

Comment: Here we go, I got it. EITHER use a simplistic approach:
Define p as u+v. p, u and v define a plane. Then, by hypothesis, p+w must equal 0. Therefore, p=-w. w is a scalar multiple of p so it must also lie in the same plane.
EITHER use triple scalar product.
Since p and u+v form a plane, uxv is perpendicular to p, and therefore to w. So the dot product of w and uxv is equal to 0. Therefore, the vectors lie in the same plane.

Comment: @GregMartin please confirm.

Comment: I think that's a correct proof. But it's also not that complicated. $u$ and $v$ together define a plane through $0$. And any linear combination of $u$ and $v$ is automatically in that plane. In particular, $(-1)u+(-1)v=w$ is in the plane.